# How can I share a GIF as og:image on Linkedin?

Tags: html, linkedin-api

I'm trying to post an animated GIF on Linkedin as image preview of my post.

This article [here](https://www.ciaomanager.com/webinar-covid-episodio6/) is able to do it. You can see it from Linkedin's post inspector: https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.ciaomanager.com%2Fwebinar-covid-episodio6%2F

But [my page](https://belkadigital.com/articles/ui-animation-101-when-you-should-use-it/) which has the same declared og:image tag is showing nothing. I have no idea on how to debug this since everything is the very same.

Any idea?

Comment: When i open your page with the inspector the gif is working just fine, the image might not have been scraped immediately.

Comment: No it wasn't that! Linkedin keeps a cache of the pictures but you can append anything after (like an hello www.google.com?hello) and it reload the website as it was new. I tried several times without success!

Answer (score 1):

Found it! It was a matter of size. Linkedin does not accepts GIF og:image bigger than 1MB

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://i.giphy.com/media/2M3hZ6Mp1ykysFnhow/giphy.gif"
    class="black-bgcolor" />

<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/gif" class="black-bgcolor" />

<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" class="black-bgcolor" />

<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" class="black-bgcolor" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).